# Can't establish connection between client and server using node js with socket.io and express and a html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I was following a Youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXBy6pB4mTU&list=PLo6lBZn6hgcZ4-xQFjDPfWnONyq9vFnh9) for a simple web game with lobbies/rooms, until I stumbled upon this problem: when trying to get the client to connect to the server, I didn't get the expected: "a user connected" text outputted to the console. I'm using a html file and Node js with express and socket.io installed. I also tried searching the internet (stack overflow, expressjs.com and https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/)for solutions but couldn't really find any useful solutions, perhaps because of my bad understanding of code.

I start my server.js via inputting "node server.js" in the Terminal of VScode and after that I start a live server of my Index.html file. The tutorial showed the expected "a user connected" (7:24 in the video) but on my side nothing happend.

node js version: 9.6.7
express version: 4.18.2
socket.io version: 4.7.2

This is my Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the client.js file:
`const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');`

Last the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const server = app.listen(port)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below these are **causing issues**. 
`const server = app.listen(port)`
`const io = require('socket.io')(server)`

#### This should work :

```js
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Hello World!');
    });
    
    //Whenever someone connects this gets executed
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
       console.log('A user connected');
       
       //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
       socket.on('disconnect', function () {
          console.log('A user disconnected');
       });
    });
    http.listen(3000, function(){
       console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn’t, plus when I don’t remove the disconnect block I get a „socket is not defined“ erorr in the console

Comment: can you share me your package.json file??

Comment: did you install socket.io npm package?

Comment: i gave up kinda, i found out it was some problem with "cors"(i dont even know what that is)